# How to eliminate duplicate object and add in to a single object

Tags: django, orm, django-views

I am having a model

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null= True)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField()
    start_date = models.DateField()
```

THis is my query for fetching the data

```
qs = Project.objects.values('project').annotate(
    total_hours=Sum((F('end_time') - F('start_time'))), start_date =F('start_date'),
).distinct()



for i in qs:
     print(i)
```

Now what I am getting is

```
{'project': '1', 'total_hours': Decimal('2.0000'), 'start_date': datetime.date(2020, 8, 1)}
{'project': '3', 'total_hours': Decimal('1.0000'), 'start_date': datetime.date(2020, 8, 1)}
{'project': '1', 'total_hours': Decimal('1.0000'), 'start_date': datetime.date(2020, 8, 2)}
```

Here if project 1 coming twise in to diffrent dates.... How to elimintate second one add as a single object

Comment: The problem is the `start_date` this will result in a `GROUP BY` id. It thus prevents aggregating over multiple projects with the same name. But nevertheless, it looks bad modeling to have the same project in a field. Usually it means you better make an extra model with the project, and rename this model to something like a `ProjectEntry` for example with a FK to `Project`.

Comment: Can we able to use my sql group_concat method in Django?

Comment: Can you try with `Project.objects.values('project_id')` ?

Comment: project is a charfield right ?

Comment: @David: `django-mysql`, a package that offers extra MySQL functions has this: https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aggregates.html#django_mysql.models.GroupConcat although I am not sure if it works with `DateField`s.